# PHP RegEx specify characters that I DO want?

Tags: php, regex

How would I strip out all characters from a string that does NOT contain: `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/_]` ?

In other words, I'd like to specify what I DO want rather than what I don't. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: Your regex originally appeared without the backslash in front of the hyphen because you didn't use backticks to format it.  The responders all copied it that way--and it works--but you should continue escaping it anyway.  Not all regex flavors are as forgiving as PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\/_]/", '', $string);
```

Another approach would be to do a match and then implode the matched values.

Comment: Wouldn't that eliminate a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, / and _ ? I don't want that. I want to KEEP those without creating a 10kb line of things I don't want.

Comment: Exactly, the little `^` hat means *everything else apart from the stuff in here*.

Comment: WOW! I mistook that as a beginning-of-string symbol. All these years and I had no idea. Thanks so much.

Comment: Well you were sort of right - it is also a beginning of string symbol. Just when used inside square brackets it gets the meaning of **not**.

Comment: @pax: Actually, it's the *character-class* NOT operator--and only if it's the first character after the opening `[`.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\/_]/", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a "/" and "\"

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\\\/_]/", '', $string);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the backslash was only there to escape the forward-slash; now that I've added code formatting to the question, you can see there's one in front of the hyphen as well.

Comment: Yes I can see that now, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way to do it:

```
echo(preg_replace('~[^\w-/]~i', '', 'H#el/-l0:0.'));
```

Outputs:

```
"Hel/-l00"
```